# create new git repository from existing source with all files (including ignored files)

Tags: git

i have a website in a remote server and i have to create new repository with this.

below this is what i did:

first i create an empty repository using bitbucket
in the remote server:

i run `git init`

then

`$ git remote add origin https://login@bitbucket.org/myworkspace/myrepository.git`

`git add .`

`git commit -m "initial commit"`

`git push origin master`

my problem is i get all files **except** those are ignored by several .gitignore but i need them to clone the repo in my local dev environment

those .gitignore files are present in several vendor folders or other

please how to get all files, included those are ignored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `git add` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> The `git add` command will not add ignored files by default. If any ignored files were explicitly specified on the command line, `git add` will fail with a list of ignored files. Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored. **The `git add` command can be used to add ignored files with the `-f` (force) option.**

**TLDR:**

Use the `-f` flag to add ignored files too